# Getting error while connecting local Database in Airbyte

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to add my local Database as Source to pull the data in Airbyte. But I'm getting below error.

[![Airbyte Connection image][1]][1]

But I can be able to connect the DataBase in DBeaver using same details. See below

[![DBeaver connection result][2]][2]

I couldn't find the issue. Please help me to resolve this issue.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iv8N.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOxQ0.png

Answer (score 0):

Give port as 5432, username: postgres & {your generated one} too these can be by default also. Leave other options as empty they are optional any way , & test the connection.